# Correct Syntax for Accessing JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a JavaScript object and I want to find a string in that object and if found, capture the associated values by splitting them on the pipe character.

```
<script>
  var market = "arizona"; 
  var marketNumbers = {
  "arizona" : "800 555-1234|866 452-8569", 
  "florida" : "800 555-4567|866 452-9999"
  };

  for (market in marketNumbers) { 
    var tmp = marketNumbers[market].split('|');
    alert(tmp(0));
  };
</script>
```

As it stands, tmp equals the two numbers separated by commas, not pipes.  No idea where the comma came from.

Comment: what you try to access is an array. not a true object. marketNumbers is a true object.

Comment: There's no pipe anymore in the array, you've just splitted it out. The comma comes from array's `toString` method, since `alert` expects a string as an argument. You're passing an array, hence it is implicitly converted.

Comment: `tmp(0)` will generate a runtime error. You shouldn't see any output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting an array back containing the split data.
you try to get the first item using `tmp(0)`, that syntax is wrong use brackets.. `tmp[0]`.
below your code is modified a little, it finds your string, and display an alert with the number fo phone numbers obtained and display the first number.

```
<script>
  var market = "arizona"; 
  var marketNumbers = {
  "arizona" : "800 555-1234|866 452-8569", 
  "florida" : "800 555-4567|866 452-9999"
  };

    var tmp = marketNumbers[market].split('|');
    alert('found '+tmp.length+' items. your first item is '+tmp[0]);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew about the (), that was a left over form previous variations I missed updating when I posted the question.  I like that this code doesn't require a FOR loop.

Comment: The for loop in my example was purely to illustrate all the values coming out of the various markets. You can access them individually, of course, using this syntax, but you didn't specify that directly in your question. Your question was asking for a generic approach.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the arrays correctly...

```
<script>
    var marketNumbers = {
        "arizona" : "800 555-1234|866 452-8569", 
        "florida" : "800 555-4567|866 452-9999"
    };

    for (var market in marketNumbers) { 
        var tmp = marketNumbers[market].split('|');
        for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
            alert('Phone Number [' + market + ']: ' + tmp[i]);
        }
    };
</script>
```